# Set one value in lambda expression based on another value set before it?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm working on an emergency monitoring tool for Canadian oil camps so the below example is extremely simplified. However, I think gets the point across.

My goal is to avoid code duplication and clean up my lambda type conversion.

For example rather than this:

```
var dto = results.Select(x => new DTO()
                {
                    Unoccupied = !(x.RoomStatusType == "Checked In" || x.RoomStatusType == "No Sleep"),
                    SwipeTime = x.RoomStatusType == "Checked In" || x.RoomStatusType == "No Sleep" ? x.SwipeTime : null,
                    Mustered = (x.RoomStatusType == "Checked In" || x.RoomStatusType == "No Sleep") && x.SwipeTime != null
                }).ToList();
```

I would like to do this:

```
var dto = results.Select(x => new DTO()
                {
                    Unoccupied = !(x.RoomStatusType == "Checked In" || x.RoomStatusType == "No Sleep"),
                    SwipeTime = Unoccupied ? null : x.SwipeTime,
                    Mustered = !Unoccupied && SwipeTime != null
                }).ToList();
```

However, in the latter implementation I get errors stating that

> The name {{ 'Unoccupied' or 'SwypeTime' respectively }} does not exist
>   in the current context.

I find this baffling since both do seem to exist within the context of the lambda expression. Prefixing them with things like "this.Unoccupied" or "dto.Unoccupied" of course do no good. This really frustrates me!

Comment: You can do this a lot easier with LINQ using a `let`.

Comment: My god stack overflow has gotten FAST! I was ready to post this and go work on something else, but it was literally solved in real time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use a local variable:

```
var dto = results.Select(x =>
    {
        var unoccupied = !(x.RoomStatusType == "Checked In" || x.RoomStatusType == "No Sleep");
        var swipeTime = unoccupied ? null : x.SwipeTime;
        return new DTO()
            {
                Unoccupied = unoccupied,
                SwipeTime = swipeTime,
                Mustered = !unoccupied && swipeTime != null
            };
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: I like this and will probably use it over the multi-line simply for the clean and readable nature of the block. However, I must suggest an edit to be consistent with the logic.

Comment: @Methodician Should be fixed now. I introduced the 2nd variable.

Answer (score 1):

The lines defining Unoccupied, SwipeTime and Mustered aren't separate statements. They are part of a single object initialization statement. The values on the right of those assignments have to already be in scope.

You could rewrite as a multi-line Lambda expression with separate assignment statements for each property, for example:

```
var dtoList = results.Select(x => {
    var dto = new DTO();
    dto.Unoccupied = !(x.RoomStatusType == "Checked In" || x.RoomStatusType == "No Sleep");
    dto.SwipeTime = dto.Unoccupied ? null : x.SwipeTime;
    dto.Mustered = !dto.Unoccupied && dto.SwipeTime != null;
    return dto;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Cool it looks like as I watched, someone else provided an example of this and then immediately deleted it! Could you provide an example?

Comment: I've added an example. This is the closest thing to what your code is attempting to do, but I think the answer from itsme86 reads better.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure which one I actually like better, but I do think the readability is better with local variables. However, he missed a spot so I'll suggest an edit to his and take a hint from which receives more upvotes before selecting an answer.